# SQL Query Price Compare

Tags: php, sql, search

I am running a SQL query to seach my database. I can currently search everything until i compare prices.

**Working Code Without Price Compare**

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM propertie_ids WHERE (`search` LIKE '%".$searchquery."%') AND (`location` = '$location') AND (`bathroom` = '$bathroom') AND (`bedroom` = '$bathroom');
```

**Broken Code With Price Compare**

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM propertie_ids WHERE (`search` LIKE '%".$searchquery."%') AND (`location` = '$location') AND (`bathroom` = '$bathroom') AND (`bedroom` = '$bathroom') AND price BETWEEN ('0') AND  ('10000000000')";
```

Any ideas why this does not work, I have checked and all my tables are named correctly.

Comment: Have you print this query and executed in mysql directly?

Comment: I think price should be in decimal/double/currency. And you're testing string values here!

Comment: I have ran both query on database, I got no errors but the working code gave me a list, and the broken did nothing. @Nadeem_MK - The price is stored in a string in my database

Comment: storing price as string is bad... :-) You'll need to use the `CAST()`-function to use numerical comparisons... Provide us with some sample data, please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single quote denote strings in SQL, so using them will cause your query to do a lexicographical comparison.
If you remove them, you'll have the numerical comparison you probably meant. Additionally, since you have `price` as a string, you'd probably need to cast that too.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM propertie_ids WHERE (`search` LIKE '%".$searchquery."%') AND (`location` = '$location') AND (`bathroom` = '$bathroom') AND (`bedroom` = '$bathroom') AND CAST (price AS DECIMAL) BETWEEN (0) AND  (10000000000)";
```

Answer (score 1):

I think price should be in decimal/double/currency. And you're testing string values here!

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM propertie_ids 
WHERE (`search` LIKE '%".$searchquery."%') AND (`location` = '$location') 
AND (`bathroom` = '$bathroom') AND (`bedroom` = '$bathroom') 
AND price BETWEEN 0 AND 10000000000";
```

And if the price is stored in string, you'll have to convert it, as you can't state a string between two strings!

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM propertie_ids 
WHERE (`search` LIKE '%".$searchquery."%') AND (`location` = '$location') 
AND (`bathroom` = '$bathroom') AND (`bedroom` = '$bathroom') 
AND CAST(price as DECIMAL(10,2)) BETWEEN 0 AND 10000000000";
```

Answer (score 1):

### http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/abbcb/4/0

I think price column should be in INT , you should remove quotes from the query , it will work. Instead of cast you can use like `price*1`

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM propertie_ids WHERE (`search` LIKE '%".$searchquery."%') AND (`location` = '$location') AND (`bathroom` = '$bathroom') AND (`bedroom` = '$bathroom') AND price BETWEEN 0 AND  10000000000";
```

or

```
`SELECT * FROM test where price*1 between '5' and '13'`
```

*Here between 0 and 10000000000 means it includes 0  and 10000000000 too.
I recommend going between 1 and 10000000000.*